# Moving tabs on chrome jumps to the primary display

Tags: google-chrome

There is a new strange behavior with chrome. When I move a tab out of a window on my secondary monitor the tab jumps to my primary monitor then I have to go grab the window and drag it back up to the screen that I was working on. It sounds weird but it's quite frustrating and it never used to be like this.

Anyone know how to revert this behavior or whether this was a Mac update or a Chrome update and what exactly was updated?

Thanks.

Comment: To add to this. And I'm not sure if it's linked. When a javascript alert appears (are you sure you want to close this tab, you have unsaved changes) That popup also pops up on the primary monitor rather than the monitor you're currently on. Which is also new, odd and frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to right click on Chrome in the dock -> click options -> None.